# Angular Ngrx store - store.select('selector name') is expected to return list of Books, but it returns a list which is not iterable

Tags: angular, typescript, selector, ngrx-store

what am i doing wrong here? This is my first attempt with using state management.

Final output when i try. to fetch it from the state

[image]

Reducer:

```
import {createReducer, on} from '@ngrx/store';
import {getBooksSuccess} from './book-list.actions';
import {Book} from '../../models/book.model';

const initialState: Array<Book> = [];

export interface BookState {
  bookList: Book[];
}


export const bookReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(getBooksSuccess, (state, action) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      books: action,
    };
  })
);

export function BookReducer(state, action) {
  return bookReducer(state, action);
}
```

Action:

```
import {createAction} from '@ngrx/store';
import {Book} from '../../models/book.model';


export const FETCH_BOOKS_START = '[Books] books start';
export const FETCH_BOOKS_SUCCESS = '[Books] books Success';


export const getBooks = createAction(
  FETCH_BOOKS_START
);

export const getBooksSuccess = createAction(
  FETCH_BOOKS_SUCCESS,
  (books: ReadonlyArray<Book>) => books
);
```

Effect:

```
fetchBooks$ = createEffect(() => {
  return this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(getBooks),
    mergeMap(() => {
      return this.bookService.getBooks().pipe(
        map((bookList) => {
          this.books = this.bookService.mapToBooksModel(bookList);
          return getBooksSuccess(this.books);
        })
      );
    })
  );
});
```

Service class

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class BookService {
  responseData: BookResponseData[];
  bookList: Book[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getBooks(): Observable<BookResponseData[]> {
    return this.http.get<BookResponseData[]>(
      `./assets/books.json`,
    );
  }

  mapToBooksModel(books: BookResponseData[]) {
      this.bookList = books;
      return this.bookList;
    }
}
```

Model class

```
export interface Book {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  author: string;
}

export interface BookResponseData {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  author: string;
}
```

Selector:

```
import {BookState} from './book-list.reducer';
import {Book} from '../../models/book.model';
import {createSelector} from '@ngrx/store';

export const BOOK_STATE_NAME = 'bookList';


export const bookSelector = createSelector(
  (state: BookState) => state.bookList,
  (books: Array<Book>) => books
);
```

```
export class BookListComponent implements OnInit {

  book$: Observable<Book[]>;
  books: Book[];

  constructor(private store: Store<BookState>) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.store.dispatch(getBooks());
   this.store.select(bookSelector).pipe().subscribe( books => {
      this.books = books;
      console.log(this.books);
    });
  }
```

Comment: What does the data in `./assets/books.json` look like. Is it really an array, or a map?

Comment: [
    {
      "id":"1849830347",
      "name":"American Assassin",
      "author":"Vince Flynn"
    },
    {
      "id":"0857208683",
      "name":"Kill Shot",
      "author":"Vince Flynn"
    }
  ]

Answer (score 1):

I guess the error lays here. You are assigning an action object to the books property, but you just need it's payload. You can either assign it like this `books: action.books` or simply destructure the action object.

```
export const bookReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(getBooksSuccess, (state, { books }) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      books
    };
  })
);
```

EDIT:
While reading your question again I noticed multiple potential issues that might be worth fixing.

```
// BookService
getBooks(): Observable<BookResponseData[]> {
  return this.http.get<BookResponseData[]>(`./assets/books.json`)
    .pipe(map(books) => {
      this.bookList = books.map(b => {...b}); //create a copy, otherwise some weird reference issues might pop up
      return this.bookList;
    });
}
// no need for 'mapToBooksModel' function now
```

Your action is defined in a weird manner. I've never seen it before, try this.

```
// books action
export const getBooksSuccess = createAction(
  FETCH_BOOKS_SUCCESS,
  props<{books: ReadonlyArray<Book>}>() // defines payload, books should be then accessible
);
```

Your effect also needs some polishing. Why are you storing the result of the service in a class property (`this.books`). It might lead to some issue where you can rewrite the state without using reducers when strict mode is off. Plus, what is happening in `getBooksSuccess` function?

```
fectchBooks$ = createEffect(() => 
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(getBooks),
    concatMap(() => this.bookService.getBooks())
    map((bookList) => getBooksSuccess(bookList))
  )
);
```

Comment: I am only able to access action.type, I am not able to access the rest of the elements.action.books is throwing an error.Property books doesnot exist on readonly Book[]

Comment: I'm just going through your question again and I see couple of other potential issues. I'll edit my answer in a while